# The center of a subring with a fix element

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

For a fix element $a \in R$ define $C(a)$ = { $r \in R$ | $ra=ar$ }.(1) Prove that $C(a)$ is a subring of $R$ containing $a$.(2) Prove that the center of $R$ is the intersection of the subring $C(a)$ over all $a \in R$. I prove the first one but i am having a little trouble with the second one. I can not see what i need to show.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Z(R)$ denote the center of $R$. We want to show $Z(R) = \cap_{a \in R} C(a)$. To see this, note $x\in Z(R) \iff xa = ax$ for all $a\in R \iff x\in C(a)$ for all $a\in R \iff x\in \cap_{a\in R} C(a)$.

Comment: cool man that was awesome

Answer (score 0):

Take an element in the center of $R$, and show it is in $C(a)$ for all $a$. This will show

$$C(R) \subset \bigcap_{a\in R} C(a) $$

Then take an element in $C(a)$ for all $a$ and show that it is in the center of R, this will show

$$ \bigcap_{a\in R} C(a)  \subset C(R)$$

Answer (score 0):

The subset $C(a)$ is usually called the centralizer of $a$.

It is a subring because if $r,s\in C(a)$, then
$$
a(r+s)=ar+as=ra+sa=(r+s)a,
\\
a(rs)=(ar)s=(ra)s=r(as)=r(sa)=(rs)a
$$
and, obviously $0\in C(a)$, $1\in C(a)$. It contains $a$ because $aa=aa$.

Now, the center $Z(R)$ of the ring $R$ is
$$
Z(R)=\{r\in R:ra=ar, \text{ for all $a\in R$}\}
$$
So, if $r\in Z(R)$, then $r\in C(a)$ for any $a\in R$. Conversely, if $r\in C(a)$ for all $a\in R$, then $ra=ar$ for all $a\in R$ and $r\in Z(R)$.